# Use nuxt/content to display markdown fetched from a database

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm using nuxt / content in my app and it's working fine. In another part of the app, I'd like to fetch some markdown from a database and display it.

```
let mytext = "Some *markdown* fetched from a db here."

<nuxt-content :document="mytext" />
```

This does not work because I'm missing a parsing step; when you do `$content("a_page_title_here").fetch()` it parses the fetched text and presents it to the  component as structured json.

How do I use `$content` to parse text, so it can be passed to the component for display?

I'll bet there is a way to do it, but the documentation does not include a reference section that describes everything you can do with `$content`.

If there is an easy way to use the underlying Remark component, I can do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### `nuxt@3` and `@nuxt/content@2`

You can use `@nuxt/content`'s [Markdown transformer](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/e82af75360c19e9ad345466e81931dbc5861a31e/src/runtime/transformers/markdown.ts) to parse an arbitrary string:

```js
// ~/utils/parseMarkdown.js
import markdownParser from '@nuxt/content/transformers/markdown'

// first arg to parse() is for id, which is unused
export const parseMarkdown = md => markdownParser.parse('custom.md', md)
```

Then render it with `@nuxt/content`'s [`ContentRendererMarkdown`](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/e82af75/src/runtime/components/ContentRendererMarkdown.vue) component like this:

```html
<script setup>
import { parseMarkdown } from '~/utils/parseMarkdown'

const result = ref(null)
const loadMarkdown = async () => {
  const data = await $fetch('https://example.com/page.md')
  result.value = await parseMarkdown(data)
}
loadMarkdown()
</script>

<template>
  <ContentRendererMarkdown :value="result" v-if="result" />
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-content-to-render-markdown-string?file=utils/parseMarkdown.ts,pages/index.vue)

### `nuxt@2` and `@nuxt/content@1`

You can use the underlying [`Markdown` class from `@nuxt/content`](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/content/parsers/markdown/index.js#L9). Its [async `toJSON()` function](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/content/parsers/markdown/index.js#L121) takes a filename or string (via [`gray-matter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter#matter)) that contains Markdown to parse, and resolves a JSON object that could be passed to `<nuxt-content>.document`.

To initialize `Markdown` with the default `rehype` plugins, use [`getDefaults()`](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/content/lib/utils.js#L4) and [`processMarkdownOptions()`](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/content/lib/utils.js#L84):

```js
// ~/utils/parseMarkdown.js
import Markdown from '@nuxt/content/parsers/markdown'
import { getDefaults, processMarkdownOptions } from '@nuxt/content/lib/utils'

export async function parseMarkdown(md) {
  const options = getDefaults()
  processMarkdownOptions(options)
  return new Markdown(options.markdown).toJSON(md) // toJSON() is async
}
```

Then use it in your component like this:

```html
<script>
import { parseMarkdown } from '~/utils/parseMarkdown'

export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const resp = await $axios.get('https://example.com/page.md')
    const page = await parseMarkdown(resp.data)
    return { page }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <nuxt-content :document="page" />
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-content-to-render-markdown-string?file=pages%2Findex.vue)

Comment: `[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Missing "./parsers/markdown" specifier in "@nuxt/content" package`. It must have been changed. I wish we could get the same output as Nuxt offers for file-based Markdown for consistency.

Comment: @Lukas Interesting. `@next/content/parsers/markdown` is from `nuxt@2` and `@nuxt/content@1`. Do you have the right versions installed? If so, you're probably right that they removed it. I haven't had a chance to check this yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have been tired and I missed the versions. I'm on Nuxt 3 and content 2... my bad.

Comment: `markdownParser.parse('custom.md', md)` returns a JSON object from a markdown string. Is there way to do the opposite.. from JSON back to a markdown string? I ask because I store the json in a database, but want to convert it to markdown so the user can edit it and then save it again as JSON once they are finished.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [tony19's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054151/20197519), I was able to create simple component which renders passed string with Markdown content dynamically. Maybe it will be useful for somebody, too!

```
<script setup>
import markdownParser from "@nuxt/content/transformers/markdown"

const props = defineProps({
  markdownString: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const record = ref("");

watchEffect(async () => {
  await markdownParser.parse("custom.md", props.markdownString).then((md) => record.value = md);
});
</script>

<template>
  <ContentRendererMarkdown :value="record" v-if="record" />
</template>
```

Component usage example:

```
<MarkdownStringRenderer :markdownString="description" />
```

Markdown will be re-rendered each time `description` changes.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use the [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) npm package.

```
npm install marked
npm install @types/marked # For TypeScript projects
```

And use like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { marked } from 'marked';

const parsedDescription = computed(() => {
  return marked.parse(description);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work?

```js
const mytext = await this.$content('a_page_title_here').fetch()
```

Comment: No, because $content looks for the text in a file on disk, and is not processing text from an external source.